# When i exec pod update,how to skip pre-download?

Tags: cocoapods

I have Podfile,which content a pod `pod 'EaseMobSDKFull', :git => 'https://github.com/easemob/sdk-ios-cocoapods-integration.git'.`
When i exec `pod update`,it willl be exec

```
 -> Pre-downloading: `EaseMobSDKFull` from `https://github.com/easemob/sdk-ios-cocoapods-integration.git`
 > Git download
 > Git download
     $ /usr/bin/git clone
     https://github.com/easemob/sdk-ios-cocoapods-integration.git
     /var/folders/sv/.../T/...
     --single-branch --depth 1
     Cloning into '/var/folders/sv/.../T/...'...
```

It will spent long time to download the git.So,how to skip this step?Please help me!